# Создание объектов или клонирование. Вопрос производительности

Tags: javascript

Есть необходимость держать пул объектов которые предоставляют доступ к уровню данных. Объекты имеют одинаковый интерфейс но разную конфигурацию (в зависимости от типа источника данных), конфигурируются объекты в момент создания параметрами которые передаются в конструктор.

По запросу управляющий объект-фабрика предоставляет экземпляр объекта-доступа такого типа который она получила в параметре запроса.

**пример**

```
UnitFactory.getUnit('unitType')
           .getData();
```

Есть два подхода реализации данного кейса.

1. В момент загрузки приложения из конфигурационного файла читаются параметры объектов-доступа, создаются эталонные объекты в конструкторы которых передаются параметры из конфиг файла, эти объекты добавляются в контейнер `map` объекта-фабрики, по вызову метода `getUnit(unitType)` возвращается копия эталонного объекта заданного типа.
2. В момент загрузки приложения из конфигурационного файла читаются параметры объектов-доступа и сохраняются в поле объекта-фабрики, по вызову метода `getUnit(unitType)` берутся ранее сохраненные параметры и создается новый объект-доступа с передачей этих параметров в конструктор после чего созданный объект возвращается.

Какой вариант предпочтительнее с точки зрения производительности? При условии что типов объектов могут быть десятки но за один сеанс может понадобится несколько, но этих несколько типов может затребоваться сотни экземпляров.

Одним словом что дешевле, каждый раз создавать объект с передачей параметров в конструктор или один раз создать а потом возвращать его копию?

Comment: так как в яваскрипте нет копирования объектов, разницы нет, в любом случае придется создавать объект и присваивать свойства. Ну и лучший способ проверить что быстрее - запустить тест

Comment: Есть такой сервис - jsperf.com

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность на каждый тип данных держать только один объект, то разумеется лучше держать один. Такой подход лучше и для вычислений, и для  памяти.

Тут ведь вопрос в другом: есть ли немоходимость вносить изменения в эти объекты? Если ответ - да, то можно ли допустить, что другой компонент системы получит объект не в исходном виде, а уже с изменениями?

Если ответом на оба вопроса будет либо да, либо нет, то можно создать на каждый тип данных только по одному объекту.